# add hash to hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

```
final_sub_hash = {}

<% workers.each do |work| %>
  <% sub_hash = {} %>
  <% sub_hash = {:name => work['name'], :gender => work['gender']} %>        
  <% final_sub_hash.update(sub_hash) %>
<% end %>
```

What I am trying to do is append the values of sub_hash to final_sub_hash but I am not able to figure out how can I do that. Please help me find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hash.store(key, value)` stores a key-value pair in `hash`.

Example:

```
hash   #=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>55}
hash["d"] =  30 #=> 30
hash   #=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>55, "d"=>30}
```

What you are trying to do is a list.

Example:

```
works = []
work.append(hash) #=> [ {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>55, "d"=>30} ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I arrived here from a search for how to add a hash to a hash. In case anyone else wonders the same, here's a nice example

```rb
# Create a hash
h = {a: 1, b: 2}
# => {:a=>1, :b=>2}

# Add a hash to the existing hash
h.store(:c, {i: 10, ii: 20})
# > {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>{:i=>10, :ii=>20}}
```

The new key can be a symbol (like `:c`, as above), but it could also be a string:

```rb
h.store("c", {i: 10, ii: 20})
# => {:a=>1, :b=>2, "c"=>{:i=>10, :ii=>20}}
```

Comment: This is analogous to `h[:c] = {i: 10, ii: 20}`